# Isabelle: Is there a difference between using axiomatization and datatype for constructors

Tags: types, constructor, isabelle

Basicly there are two ways to define a constructor for my datatype:

```
typedecl basicTest
datatype test= af basicTest | plus test test (infixl "+" 35)
```

or i use axiomatization:

```
typedecl basicTest
datatype test= af basicTest
axiomatization
plus :: "test ⇒ test ⇒ test " (infixl "+" 35)
```

I am blissfully unaware of any differences, but i guess there are some :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many differences. Only the former gives you the right induction principle for your data type, lemmas that ensure that `plus a b` is something different from `af b`, and will allow you define functions by pattern matching on `af` and `plus`.

The latter really defines `test` as a type that is isomorphic to `basicTest`, and claims the existence of a an otherwise unspecified function `plus` on it.

In other words, the two definitions define very different types (and the axiomatization of `plus` does not change the type).

Answer (score 1):

As a general principle, the command `print_theorems` may be used after some specification command, to tell which are the relevant theorems that characterize the newly introduced logical entities.  Alternatively, the Prover IDE provides a Query panel with "Print context / theorems".

For the above `typedecl` and `axiomatization` (without actual axioms) the result is empty.

For `datatype` you get tons of facts that may be used later in your proofs.

Side-remarks:

- camel-case is not used in Isabelle, words_are_separated_by_underscore
- type names, most const names etc. are in lower_case (main exception: datatype constructors are Capitalized)
- theory names are Captalized (concept usually in singular)